# OnTriggerEnter2D play animation not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to make a code, where it detects when Text in Canvas equals "Cherries: 12".

Visual Studio don't say I written any wrong code, Unity Editor don't too, but it doesn't work.

Do anyone know how can I do this?

(NOTE: I assigned Text component, so `public UnityEngine.UI.Text txt;` is probably working fine)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TrpohyForCherries : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text txt;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(txt.Equals("Cherries: 12"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Trophy Unlocked!");
            GameJolt.API.Trophies.Unlock(******);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just modify the condition to : 
`if(txt.text.Equals("Cherries: 12"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Trophy Unlocked!");
            GameJolt.API.Trophies.Unlock(******);
        }`

Comment: The title has no resemblance to the question

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a textbox with a string. Instead of using txt.Equals, you should use txt.text.Equals because the text inside the textbox is found in Textbox's text variable. Note that the variable might be Text or text. Example:

```
if(txt.text.Equals("test")){
    //assign trophy
}
```